# codeigniter upload image code url error

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, codeigniter-2

This is regarding codeigniter image upload and image manipulation day 9 from

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation/

This code is not compatible with the latest CI, i think.

i get an error

"The requested URL /codeigniter/gallery was not found on this server."

my htaccess is set to remove index.php
I have set my base url to localhost/codeigniter

model

```
<?php
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model {

var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function Gallery_model() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'images';
}

function do_upload() {

    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration' => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

}

function get_images() {

    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $images []= array (
            'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . $file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'thumbs/' . $file
        );
    }

    return $images;
}

}
```

controller

```
<?php
class Gallery extends CI_Controller {

function index() {

    $this->load->model('Gallery_model');

    if ($this->input->post('upload')) {
        $this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
    }

    $data['images'] = $this->Gallery_model->get_images();

    $this->load->view('gallery', $data);

}

}
```

Comment: First of all, you need `public function __construct() not function Gallery_model()`. Second of all, you don't need APPPATH, just define it with `'./yourpath'`

Answer (score 0):

did you tryed with absolute url?

make a test, instead of `base_url()` use the enteire path `"http://mywebsite.com/path/to/gallery"`

if it works with absolute url it means you are using worng url path and then you can fix it